# MUI AutoComplete default value not shown?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [top100Films, settop100Films] = React.useState([]);
  const value = 1;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        settop100Films(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
  // if (!top100Films.length > 0) {
  //   return "";
  // }
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      defaultValue={
        top100Films.find((ele) => ele.id === value) || null
      }
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(data) => data.first_name}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  );
}
```

If i uncomment this **if condition** it works fine. But i don't want that behaviour. Initially defalutValue will be null. After fetching data default value will be changed to the exact value. But the value not shown in autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In the defaultValue you should not use console.log, you can try like this:

```js
value ={top100Films}
```

Comment: Used but not showing default selected value.

Comment: Update my answer, you can try to use:

value={top100Films}

Comment: @wildgamer value prop it's a single option but not an array of them..)